# Custom Cell Reuse Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am loading a custom cell into a table view, and notice that my cell is not being re-used correctly.  I am using a NSFetchedResultsController to pull the results from Core Data.

I am loading the cell from a nib.  The cell identifier is setup in interface builder.  The cells appear to get re-used because I am not creating a new cell everytime I scroll the table.  However, the data is not being displayed correctly on the cells.

```
// BeerCell.h
@interface BeerCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *beerImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *displayBeerName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *displayBeerType;

@end

// BeerCell.m
@implementation BeerCell

@synthesize beerImage;
@synthesize displayBeerName;
@synthesize displayBeerType;

@end

 // Code where i'm setting up the cells for the tableView

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BeerCell";

    BeerCell *cell = (BeerCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeerCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){

            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (BeerCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }

        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    }        

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(BeerCell *)cell 
          atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    Beer *beer = (Beer *) [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.displayBeerName.text = beer.name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the configureCell function call outside the if block.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BeerCell";

    BeerCell *cell = (BeerCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeerCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){

            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (BeerCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }        
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I can not believe I did not see that.  On a side note, do I need to implement prepareForUse for in the Cell custom class?